# Java MongoDB bulk insert from stream

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to insert a few million documents into MongoDB in one operation. Using `MongoCollection.insertMany` does not work for me because it takes a `List` as input and my data does not fit in memory.

Is it possible to insert documents from a stream instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use Bulk Insert operations from your stream. please read:
[Bulk Insert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/)

try to execute() the bulk after a reasonable number of documents (inside your consumer lambda) because after all there is a limit to the size of the request Mongo can handle.